# CakePHP Custom Dropdown Menu

Tags: cakephp, dropdownbox

I have a dropdown list and the items are quite a lot (over 20 items).

I am using CakePHP and this is how I code my dropdown list:

```
<?php
     echo '<div class="form-group">';
     echo $this->Form->input('type', array(
         'class' => 'form-control',
         'id' => 'listType',
         'options' => array(
                'Item 1' => 'Item 1',
                'Item 2' => 'Item 2',
                'Item 3' => 'Item 3'),
         'empty' => '--Choose Item Type--',
         'label' => false
     ));
     echo '</div>';
?>
```

Now, there are some items in my dropdown list which have sub-items. Is there any way to do that?

For example, just like this kind of dropdown:

```
Fruits
   Apple
   Banana
   Orange
   Grape
Vegetables
   Carrot
   Potato
Chips
Sausage
```

I want ALL items EXCEPT with sub-items to be clickable. I also want ALL sub-items to be clickable.

So in short, items 'Fruits' and 'Vegetables' cannot be clicked, while the rest can be clicked. And is there any way to put a divider?

Thank you! It would be better if someone could provide an example using CakePHP format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after a few experimentation I finally figured out how to do it.

```
<?php
     echo '<div class="form-group">';
     echo $this->Form->input('type', array(
         'class' => 'form-control',
         'id' => 'listType',
         'options' => array(
                'Item 1' => 'Item 1',
                'Item 2' => array(
                     'Subitem 1' => 'Subitem 2',
                     'Subitem 2' => 'Subitem 2'
                ),
                'Item 3' => 'Item 3'),
         'empty' => '--Choose Item Type--',
         'label' => false
     ));
     echo '</div>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
you should try this.
<?php
$data=array(
    'Fruits'=>array(
    'Apple',
    'Banana','Orange','Grape'),
    'Vegetables'=>array('Carrot','Potato'),
    'Chips',
    'Sausage'
);
         echo '<div class="form-group">';
         echo $this->Form->input('type', array(
             'class' => 'form-control',
             'id' => 'listType',
             'options' =>$data,
             'empty' => '--Choose Item Type--',
             'label' => false
         ));
```

Comment: One question: what's the difference between putting the array inside a variable and putting the array directly inside the 'options' attribute?